# Refresh MathJax after loading new view in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I have more or less simple html-pages with mathematical formulas which are rendered by MathJax. I am building now a new system using AngularJS, starting from the angular-seed. All individual html-files are included as partials. 
As expected, MathJax renders correctly only if I refresh the page, when I load it trough the framework, the Math-Expressions are not rendered.

I have to run this function somewhere:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

It should run after each load of a partial to render the formulas correctly. How can I do this?

M

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the same problem you've described, I've found a quick if somewhat inelegant solution: include a second copy of `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);`. For example here's part of my controller, where I want to have MathJax re-typeset after updating the scope:

```
function selectLesson(name){
        $scope.page = name.Path;
        if(!$mdMedia('gt-md')){
            $scope.toggleSideNav('left');
        }
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
    }
```

Because MathJax loads asynchronously ([check out the MathJax Doc](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html)) , running `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` will wait until the page reloads to re-typeset the page. Running the same command again causes the typeset to occur immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a directive triggered by an attribute.  So your HTML would look like:

```
<span eqn-bind="$F = ma$"></label>
```

and your directive:

```
.directive('eqnBind', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            // Use this if it's a one-time thing and you don't need to re-render equations once they've been
            // inserted into the DOM.
            var value = $scope.$eval($attrs.esduEqnBind);
            $element.html(value);
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Reprocess", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
            
            /*
            // Use this if you need to re-render eqns that already exist on the page or are going to need constant updates
            $scope.$watch($attrs.eqnBind, function (value) {
                $element.html(value);
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Reprocess", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
            });
            */
        }]
    };
})
```

The second (commented out) part of the directive is more-or-less the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087146/getting-mathjax-to-update-after-changes-to-angularjs-model/16646667#16646667) from '[Getting MathJax to update after changes to AngularJS model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087146/getting-mathjax-to-update-after-changes-to-angularjs-model)'.

The first part doesn't require a $watch so should be a bit more efficient.

As an aside - I've discovered [katex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/), which seems much lighter and quicker. Using katex the above becomes:

```
.directive('eqnBind', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            // Use this if it's a one-time thing and you don't need to re-render equations once they've been
            // inserted into the DOM.
            var value = $scope.$eval($attrs.eqnBind);
            $element.html(value);
            renderMathInElement($element[0], { delimiters: [{ left: "$", right: "$", display: false }] });

            /*
            // Use this if you need to re-render eqns that already exist on the page...
            $scope.$watch($attrs.eqnBind, function (value) {
                $element.html(value);
                renderMathInElement($element[0], {delimiters:[{ left: "$", right: "$", display: false }]});
            });
            */
        }]
    };
})
```

Comment: How to use this inside ng-repeat?

Comment: @RAMESHKUMAR. It should just work.  I use it inside ng-repeats.