# Angular Binding to MathJax - UI Router Inconsistent?

Tags: angularjs, mathjax, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI Router with MathJax. When I route to a new state, the MathJax does **not** get processed. What burns my noodle is that if I have an update button **with exactly the same code** it works. Just not by itself.

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fk52vN5qdpj57m7k8zcS?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<p id="MathExample"><strong>Equation:</strong> {{data.equation}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

**JS**

```
$stateProvider.state('route1', {
  url: "/route1",
  templateUrl: "route1.html",
  controller: function($scope, $http){

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
       MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
       //You would think that the value would be updated here!
    })

    $scope.update = function($scope){
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
      //This works just fine, but is not automatic.
    }

  }
 });
```

I'm trying to figure out why this is the case. Do I need to use $apply? One [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087146/getting-mathjax-to-update-after-changes-to-angularjs-model) hinted at the use of a directive. However, I don't need this function. I really just need the JSON data with the math expressions to reliably become typeset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to wait for the DOM to settle down before MathJax can process it. A simple `setTimeout` call seems to fix the issue:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  setTimeout(function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  });
});
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/xIVvUHntVZ7lftGz9cDn?p=preview for an example.

---

You mentioned using a directive; you could use one to abstract away the need to call the MathJax function manually at all.

In this example, I've created a directive called `math` that automatically lays out whatever's passed in with MathJax:

```javascript
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");//Was defaulting to route 1. No more

  $stateProvider.state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      templateUrl: "route1.html",
      controller: function($scope, $http, $timeout){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;
        });
      }
  });

});

myapp.directive('math', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      math: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('math', function(value) {
        if (!value) return;
        elem.html(value);
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, elem[0]]);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<hr>
<h3>Route 1's data</h3>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  {{data.name}}
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Equation:</strong>
  <span math="{{data.equation}}"></span>
</p>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/c9NBXXd9kF7Jne6saS3i?p=preview for a demonstration.

Going this route, absolutely anything passed to the `math` directive will be automatically rendered with MathJax whenever it changes. See [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJSEGtBKSrKLjiwuLsl5?p=preview) for an example that lets you edit the equation: http://plnkr.co/edit/dJSEGtBKSrKLjiwuLsl5?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I appreciate the modified Plunker. I figured it had something to do with the rendering timing. I don't understand the timeout though. There is no set time period. Is this some kind of Angular hack? Or are you saying: "when this success function is completed, do the following"?

Comment: `setTimeout` defaults to a delay of `0`. You don't need to use Angular's `$timeout` service, as you don't need a digest cycle for MathJax to work. I've also updated the answer with some more information, including how you might go about building a directive.

Comment: Great answer. Very thorough. The directive is an interesting twist.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to modify Math on the page before it is rendered. You can use the `$timeout` to wait until it is rendered:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");//Was defaulting to route 1. No more

  $stateProvider.state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      templateUrl: "route1.html",
      controller: function($scope, $http, $timeout){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;
          $timeout(function() {
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
          }, 0);
        })
        $scope.update = function($scope){
          MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
        }
      }
  });
});
```