# combine two directives for text manipulation in one element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Edit**: The plunk for this questions is http://plnkr.co/edit/mlKyL1.

I have two angular directives which both transform text; one from MarkDown to HTML (see [here](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive)), one from MathJax ("LaTeX") to HTML (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26314698/353337)). For simplicity, let's call them

```
<div directive1="textCtrl.body"></div>
<div directive2="textCtrl.body"></div>
```

(Here, `textCtrl.body` is sourced from an input `textarea` and updates live.)

Now, I would like to combine the two such that `textCtrl.body` is first run through `directive1`, the result then through `directive2`. To achieve this, I put the `textCtrl.body` into a model and have both directives depend on it.

```
<div ng-model="textCtrl.body" directive1 directive2></div>
```

both directives look approximately like

```
app.directive('directive1', function ($compile) {
return {
  require: "ngModel",
  restrict: 'A',
  priority: 10,
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    scope.$watch(
      function() {return ngModel.$modelValue;},
      function(modelValue) {
        modelValue += "1"; // do something meaningful here one day
        element.html(modelValue);
      });
  }
};
});
```

If the `priority` of `directive1` is *lower* than the priority of `directive2`, it gets executed first. However, the contents of `element` that the `directive2` receives is still the original `modelValue`, not the one manipulated by `directive1`. Consequently, only `2` gets appended to `modelValue` in the output.

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Comment: Try using the Priority property on the directive.

Comment: @RobJ Can you be more specific? How do I combine the two directives `btf-markdown` and `mathjax` into one element?

Comment: Did you try adding both attributes onto the div in the order you want them?

Comment: @embee Both with the `"textCtrl.body"` argument? That doesn't work; only the directive with the higher priority seems to be applied.

Comment: See [this](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/priority/) example for priority on directives

Comment: @RobJ Thanks for the hint. I was able to use the `priority` keyword, but the example doesn't point out how to manipulate the contents of the element correctly.